# Loop array into button onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have this array and want to loop into buttons. The first cell will be in onclick event, the second will be in innerHTML.
And append these buttons to div

The array:

```
rows = [
  [fun1(), 'innerhtml'],
  [fun2(), 'innerhtml'],
  [fun3(), 'innerhtml'],
];
```

Comment: Are you looking to create these buttons to the DOM and apply an onclick event to them upon creation?

Comment: The onclick events from the array to be looped

Comment: Are you sure that you want to put the function return value as the onclick event handler? or should the function `fun1` be called on the onclick event?

Comment: The first button will be: <button onclick="fun1()"> innerHTML</button>

Comment: You need to remove the `()`'s from your array - those invoke the function. If you want to use those functions as callbacks, just specify their bindings without invoking them.

Comment: Can I put them in quotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you working as you would expect.

```
const fun1 = () => alert("Hello function 1");
const fun2 = () => alert("Hello function 2");
const fun3 = () => alert("Hello function 3");

const rows = [
  [fun1, 'innerhtml'],
  [fun2, 'innerhtml'],
  [fun3, 'innerhtml'],
];

const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

rows.forEach(row => {
    // Create button
    const button = document.createElement('button');

    // Apply onclick event
    button.onclick = row[0];
    button.innerHTML = row[1];

    // Append to div
    myDiv.appendChild(button);
})
```

```js
const fun1 = () => alert("Hello function 1");
const fun2 = () => alert("Hello function 2");
const fun3 = () => alert("Hello function 3");

const rows = [
  [fun1, 'innerhtml'],
  [fun2, 'innerhtml'],
  [fun3, 'innerhtml'],
];

const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

rows.forEach(row => {
    // Create button
    const button = document.createElement('button');

    // Apply onclick event
    button.onclick = row[0];
    button.innerHTML = row[1];

    // Append to div
    myDiv.appendChild(button);
})
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

The comments should explain what is happening throughout my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I wanted.